# Short cut for a check for null and assigning a value to it if it is?

Tags: c#, c#-8.0, null-check

With the new C# 8 capabilities is there a short cut now for this null-check code structure?

```
if (App.selectedPhrases == null)
    App.selectedPhrases = App.DB.GetSelectedPhrases();
```

Comment: `App.selectedPhrases ??= App.DB.GetSelectedPhrases();`

Comment: First result in google: _"C# 8.0 introduces the null-coalescing assignment operator `??=` . You can use the `??=` operator to assign the value of its right-hand operand to its left-hand operand only if the left-hand operand evaluates to null ."_  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is called [Null-coalescing assignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#null-coalescing-assignment):

```
App.selectedPhrases ??= App.DB.GetSelectedPhrases();
```

> C# 8.0 introduces the null-coalescing assignment operator ??=. You can use the ??= operator to assign the value of its right-hand operand to its left-hand operand only if the left-hand operand evaluates to null.

Answer (score 4):

```
App.selectedPhrases ??= App.DB.GetSelectedPhrases();
```