# The behavior of null-coalescing assignment operator

Tags: c#, .net-core, c#-8.0

I just wonder that how **??=** operator runs in the background. I have two questions about it.

Consider the following example,

```
string name = "John";
name ??= "George";
```

**1)** Is it equal to `name = name ?? "George";`

**2)**
Does it work like this,

```
if (name == null) {
   name = "George";
}
```

**or**

```
if (name == null) {
   name = "George";
}
else {
   name = name;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59300172/2946329

Comment: `if (name != null)` – did you mean `==` here? And both those cases are basically the same, because `else` branch does nothing meaningful (and would likely be thrown away by the compiler)

Comment: It's the same as the first version from 2). If you were to write the second version yourself, you would see that the code from the else branch would be optimized away by the compiler.

Comment: Furkan, `if (name != null) {` should be `if (name == null) {` instead

Comment: You'll want to refer to the language design proposal, which includes the lowered form:
https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/csharp-8.0/null-coalescing-assignment.md

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It will be evaluated to this:

```
string text = "John";
if (text == null)
{
    text = "George";
}
```

You can use the `sharplab` to see what happens actually:

https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQMwAJboMLoN7LpGYZQAs6AsgBQCU+hxTUcADOgHYCGAtgKboAvOgBEAKQD2ACw4iA3Mm790AfhXCRAcT4SATgHM+8xkQC+yU0A

Further Info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59300172/2946329

Based on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#null-coalescing-assignment):

> C# 8.0 introduces the null-coalescing assignment operator ??=. You can
>   use the ??= operator to assign the value of its right-hand operand to
>   its left-hand operand only if the left-hand operand evaluates to null.

Comment: What about my first question?

Comment: @FurkanÖztürk: Please do not ask two questions in one question. As you've just discovered, what happens typically is that only one of them gets answered. If you have two questions, post two different questions.

Answer (score 3):

According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator)

> null-coalescing assignment operator `??=` assigns the value of its
>   right-hand operand to its left-hand operand only if the left-hand
>   operand evaluates to `null`. The `??=` operator doesn't evaluate its
>   right-hand operand if the left-hand operand evaluates to non-null.

In you code sample it won't be evaluated, since `name` isn't `null`

```cs
string name = "John";
name ??= "George";
```

It will work if you write something like that

```cs
string name = null;
name ??= "George";
```

Name value will be `George`. Expanded variant is

```cs
if (name is null) //or name == null
{
    name = "George";
}
```

> The null-coalescing operator `??` returns the value of left-hand
>   operand if it isn't `null`; otherwise, it evaluates the right-hand
>   operand and returns result.

In this sample `name = name ?? "George"` the result will be `George` only when name has `null` value before. I your sample `name = name ?? "George";` is equal to `name ??= "George";` in terms of return result. But in both cases you can get a `George` value only when original `name` is `null` before assigning. You can also refer to [language specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#the-null-coalescing-operator) for details

Comment: What about my first question?

Comment: @FurkanÖztürk I'm updating an answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://sharplab.io/ to test for differences. The difference between `??=` and `??` is very small, and actually *disappears* once the code is JIT-compiled.

In short :

1. Once the code is compiled to assembly, it's the same.
2. The equivalent is :

```
if (text == null){
    text = "George";
}
```

**SharpLab Examples**

The code for [this example](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFAGIB2BXANlghgIywFMACItA45KAZhNhIGESBvZEj+uqAFhIFk4ACgCUrdp0lQ4ABhIUAtqQC8JAEQApAPYALNGoDcEyZ0WkA/OdVqA4kS0AnAOZFDxk9ICcQsyKNJJAF93d1p6Pn4YUXEAkw5pOTMSa209N1i4pNUkkkt1O0cXdLj4uG9ffyDkQKA==) :

```
public void M1() {
    string name = "John";
     name ??= "George";
    Console.WriteLine(name);
}

public void M2() {
    string name = "John";
    name = name  ?? "George";
    Console.WriteLine(name);
}
```

Generates this intermediate C# code, that shows a real difference :

```
public void M1()
{
    string text = "John";
    if (text == null)
    {
        text = "George";
    }
    Console.WriteLine(text);
}

public void M2()
{
    string text = "John";
    text = (text ?? "George");
    Console.WriteLine(text);
}
```

The IL though is [almost the same](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAAgJgIwFgBQBiAdgK4QQCGARhAKYAEV+F1OyAzDWjQMI0DeONA9m2QAWGgFl0ACgCUvfoMXJ0ABhoMAtrQC8NAEQApAPYALfHoDcCxYM20A/Pd16A4lSMAnAOZVL1m8oAnFJ2MlbYigC+/v6s7GLiqLLyETYCymp2NM7GZn6paVm6WTSO+m6ePvlp6ejBoeFROJFAA==), except for a `dup` (copy) and `pop` operation. You'd think that `??` is somewhat slower for this :

```
    IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: ldstr "John"
    IL_0006: stloc.0
    IL_0007: ldloc.0
    IL_0008: brtrue.s IL_0010
    IL_000a: ldstr "George"
    IL_000f: stloc.0
    IL_0010: ldloc.0
    IL_0011: call void [System.Console]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
    IL_0016: nop
    IL_0017: ret
```

vs

```
        IL_0000: nop
        IL_0001: ldstr "John"
        IL_0006: stloc.0
        IL_0007: ldloc.0
***     IL_0008: dup
        IL_0009: brtrue.s IL_0011
***     IL_000b: pop
        IL_000c: ldstr "George"
        IL_0011: stloc.0
        IL_0012: ldloc.0
        IL_0013: call void [System.Console]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
        IL_0018: nop
        IL_0019: ret
```

BUT [the assembly in Release mode](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LghgzgtgPgAgJgIwFgBQBiAdgVwDZ5gBGeApgASlbFnpwDM5i5AwuQN7rndONwAs5ALJIAFAEoOXHjLhIADOWpQKAXnIAiAFIB7ABZYNAbmkyeyigH5L6jQHFSOgE4BzUsdNm5ATlEXxJmgyAL6engxMgkIIElJBZtxyihbktroGHvEJKeop5NaaDs5umQmJSL7+gSHowUA===) is identical:

```
C.M1()
    L0000: mov ecx, [0x1a58b46c]
    L0006: test ecx, ecx
    L0008: jnz L0010
    L000a: mov ecx, [0x1a58b470]
    L0010: call System.Console.WriteLine(System.String)
    L0015: ret

C.M2()
    L0000: mov ecx, [0x1a58b46c]
    L0006: test ecx, ecx
    L0008: jnz L0010
    L000a: mov ecx, [0x1a58b470]
    L0010: call System.Console.WriteLine(System.String)
    L0015: ret
```